# List events for specific day in Android 4+ (ALL_DAY issue)

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-calendar

I'm attempting to get all events happening on selected day in Android 4+.

As far as I understand, CalendarContract.Instances is the easiest way of getting events, since it handles both recurring events and single time events.

However, I have some problems with its way of handling timestamps. To be specific, it seems to treat ALL_DAY events differently.

I've started with the following code (`start` is the day for which I'm fetching events, millisecond "maths" is to avoid unnecessary events beginning on the 12 am of the next day, Calendar uses default timezone).

```
public Cursor fetchCursor(Calendar start) {
    Calendar end = (Calendar) start.clone();
    end.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    long startTime = start.getTimeInMillis() + 1;
    long endTime = end.getTimeInMillis() - 1;

    ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    return CalendarContract.Instances.query(resolver, projection, startTime, endTime);
}
```

This code seems to work well with many edge cases, different timezones, events that span multiple days... everything except all day events.

When I examined returned event with ALL_DAY flag:

```
    Cursor c = fetchCursor(date);
    Log.e("SIZE", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        long begin = c.getLong(2); // CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN
        long end = c.getLong(3);   // CalendarContract.Instances.END
        Date beginDate = new Date(begin);
        Date endDate = new Date(end);
        Log.e("EVENT", String.valueOf(begin) + " - " + String.valueOf(end));
        Log.e("EVENT", beginDate.toString() + " - " + endDate.toString());
    }
```

I got: `EVENT(10075): Thu Sep 13 02:00:00 CEST 2012 - Sat Sep 15 02:00:00 CEST 2012`.

For me it looks like `query` expects range begin and end in millis since epoch in MY TIMEZONE (yet API states it needs UTC based timestamp). But events marked as ALL_DAY use millis since epoch in UTC (so I get 2 additional hours because of +2 timezone).

I also tried calculating and adding timezone offset. Then all day events worked fine but everything else... not.

```
private long getTimezoneOffset(TimeZone zone, long date) {
    long delta = zone.getOffset(date);
    return delta;
}

private long getTimeInUTC(Calendar date) {
    long time = date.getTimeInMillis();
    time += getTimezoneOffset(date.getTimeZone(), time);
    return time;
}

public Cursor fetchCursor(Calendar start) {
    Calendar end = (Calendar) start.clone();
    end.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    long startTime = getTimeInUTC(start) + 1;
    long endTime = getTimeInUTC(end) - 1;

    ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    return CalendarContract.Instances.query(resolver, projection, startTime, endTime);
}
```

While there is quite easy way to fix this issue by iterating over cursor, altering ALL_DAY events and removing unnecessary events, I would like to know if there is a better way. Or maybe this is Android bug? But if it is a bug then why System Calendar works OK? This inconsistent behavior seems odd to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example of how you manually do this??? I'm confused

Comment: yeah, google's calendar api seems pretty buggy...there are lot of quite childhood and stupid bugs in this api :(

Comment: It's 2014 and the bug seems to persist... ALL_DAY events use the timezone and not UTC as they should. See this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14051

Comment: Did you ever resolve how to handle this gracefully? I'm going to stick a bounty on it otherwise! Struggling with exactly the same issue.

Comment: Similar question from me and I put a bounty on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516398/query-of-all-day-events-using-calendarcontract-instances-results-in-wrong-time.  A hack that seems to work, though, is to set your formatter to UTC when displaying an all_day event.  E.g.  if (isAllDay)   formatter.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone ("UTC"));

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar` api is also a some what device dependent, your code is working perfectly in `Android - 4.4.4 KitKat` but not in other devices. The following code is working perfectly all devices in which i have tested.

Try this:

```
public Cursor fetchCursor(Calendar start) {
    Calendar end = (Calendar) start.clone();
    end.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
    return CalendarContract.Instances.query(resolver,  new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, start.getTimeInMillis(),
                end.getTimeInMillis());
}
```